# Custom UITableViewCell with Image and Label

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some `TableView` using a basic or subtitle `UITableViewCell` and displaying an image/icon. The separator line is automatically indented and starts where the labels are displayed. So far so good. ([see correct behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q26DE.png))

Now I need a couple more labels and an image. Therefore, I created a custom `TableViewCell` with 4 labels. Without the image they work as expected. But when I add an image to the existing standard `ImageView`, the image is displayed, the separator line is indented but the custom labels are not. They overlay the image. ([see wrong behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjPH5.png))

Do I have to create a custom `ImageView` as well to get it working correctly and how is the separator line indented on that way or is there another possibility / state of the art to do something like that?

Comment: Are you using autolayout constraint ???

Comment: You can set Autoresizing constraints like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669208/how-to-resize-custom-uitableviewcell-nib-file-to-fit-tableview/34670166#34670166

Comment: How you have added the labels and image view ?? in code itself or in .xib file ??

Comment: I added the labels and image view in the *.xib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended with the solution that I created an empty Interface Builder document, added a `TableViewCell`, put the `Label` and `ImageView` on it, set the constraints, connected everything to the corresponding *.swift file. Finish. I hoped to reuse the `ImageView` from the default `TableViewCell` but obviously that did not work correctly (or I was too stupid).

Answer (score 0):

**1. First off create an outlet of all the four custom elements like label and image view as :-** lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree, imageView, respectively.

**2. Then go to view Viewdidload and create a dictionary :-**

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@" @"superview":self.view,
                                      @"lblOne":self.lblOne,
                                      @"lblTwo":self.lblTwo,
                                      @"lblThree":self.lblThree,
                                      @"imageView":self.imageView
                                      };
```

**3. Now add the Autolayout constraint programmatically :-**

```
 NSArray *lblOutletCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[superView]-(<=1)-[lblOne]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:lblOutletCenterConstraint];

NSArray *lblOutletCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[superView]-(<=1)-[lblTwo]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:lblOutletCenterConstraint];

NSArray *captionTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lblOne]-25-[imageView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:captionTopConstraint];

NSArray *captionTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lblTwo]-25-[lblThree]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:captionTopConstraint];
```

**4. Or you can do that by storyboard also.**